# Appium + selenium grid: Appium successfully registers to grid but doesn't make status calls

Tags: java, selenium, appium, selenium-grid

My Appium + selenium grid has been workin fine up until a few days ago.
Now when i start my appium node it'll register onto the local grid:

```
"Appium successfully registered with the the grid on http://localhost:4444"
```

However it no longer sends get status calls like before and the grid will mark it as down
and clean it up as a stale session after some time or if you try to use the node.

```
java -jar /Users/pa23053/git/mobile-tools/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
    08:59:44.265 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
    08:59:44.354 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
    2022-08-26 08:59:44.846:INFO::main: Logging initialized @942ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
    08:59:44.997 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
    08:59:44.998 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://172.20.101.225:4444/grid/register/
    08:59:44.998 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://172.20.101.225:4444/wd/hub
    08:59:58.410 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://0.0.0.0:49915
    09:02:39.295 INFO [DefaultRemoteProxy.onEvent] - Marking the node http://0.0.0.0:49915 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
    09:04:00.616 INFO [DefaultRemoteProxy.onEvent] - Unregistering the node http://0.0.0.0:49915 because it's been down for 81321 milliseconds
```

After registering appium should regularly send these calls:

```
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status
[debug] [GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"2.0.0-beta.43"}} 
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status
......
```

Instead now it just registers and then does nothing. So far the attempts at fixing have been:
Uninstalling + reinstalling appium.
upgrading and downgrading appium.
Switching selenium server versions.
The capabilities of the simulators that are being used should be fine as they haven't changed in a while and others use them without issue.

Any suggestions of things i should check or try would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this myself. There was a weird issue were my laptop was setting my home networks Subnet mask to 255.255.252.0. This should've been 255.255.255.0. This caused an issue with either appium or selenium's ability to send/receive requests.

This explains why everything would work fine when i tried at office & while on mobile hotspot.